# Painel administrativo modificando/alterando contéudo svg

Tags: mysql, estrutura-de-dados, svg, diretório

Estava imaginando uma estrutura de página assim, mas não sei se é possível executar e queria saber os caminhos e possibilidades.

[image: detalhes]

Em uma `div` teria dados da tabela do mysql e um `svg`. Os objetos do `svg`, ao clicar, abriria um modal.

A idéia disso é pensar os objetos como cadeiras de um evento. A pessoa estaria escolhendo uma cadeira pra ela.

o `svg` é um mapa dos assentos, dependendo do local do evento, mudaria o `svg`.

**O objetivo**

Em um painel administrativo php alterar conteúdo da página.

**Prática do objetivo**

Vou realizar um novo evento e quero cadastrar outro mapa de assentos sem editar arquivos “manualmente”, tendo que ter só o novo `svg`.

**Perguntas**

Posso estar guardando no diretório o `svg` e no cadastro/alteração puxar o caminho dele ? Mais especificamente, incluir o código dele dentro da `div` ?

Posso estar gerando um arquivo, uma página nova ao cadastrar, e salvando automaticamente no diretório, no futuro quando eu quiser ter dois eventos ao mesmo tempo no site ?

Comment: O source desse SVG vai estar armazenado no banco de dados? Em arquivo? Um simples `if($_GET['evento'] == 1) echo="path/do/svg/evento1.svg";` não resolve seu problema?

Comment: @daniel, tinha colocado na cabeça que banco de dados não recebia arquivo, mas estava completamente enganado, tanto que na minha dúvida só mencionei salvar o arquivo no diretório, vou ver sobre isso certinho!